# Is there a way to create another while loop or continue this while loop on another condition

Tags: php, loops

I have a while loop that calculates the amount of change after a transaction and gives you the count in bills but now i am trying to do the change. For some reason another while loop is not working. I tried using another while loop but it wont work and I cant put it back into the first while loop since change is already less then 1.

```php
<?php
    $total_cost = (float) $_POST['total_cost'];
    $amount_provided = (float) $_POST['amount_provided'];
    $change = $amount_provided - $total_cost;

    while ($change > 1) {

        if ($change >= 50) {
            $bills50output = (int) ($change / 50);
            $bills50 = (50 * (int) ($change / 50));
            $change -= $bills50;
            if ($bills50output > 1) {
                echo "You get $bills50output $50 bills";
            } else {
                echo "You get $bills50output $50 bill";
            }
        } elseif ($change >= 20) {
            $bills20output = (int) ($change / 20);
            $bills20 = (20 * (int) ($change / 20));
            $change -= $bills20;
            if ($bills20output > 1) {
                echo "You get $bills50output $20 bills";
            } else {
                echo ", $bills20output $20 bill";
            }
        } elseif ($change >= 10) {
            $bills10output = (int) ($change / 10);
            $bills10 = (10 * (int) ($change / 10));
            $change -= $bills10;
            if ($bills10output > 1) {
                echo ", $bills10output $10 bills";
            } else {
                echo ", $bills10output $10 bill";
            }
        } elseif ($change >= 5) {
            $bills5output = (int) ($change / 5);
            $bills5 = (5 * (int) ($change / 5));
            $change -= $bills5;
            if ($bills5output > 1) {
                echo ", $bills5output $5 bills";
            } else {
                echo ", $bills5output $5 bill";
            }
        } elseif ($change >= 1) {
            $bills1output = (int) ($change / 1);
            $bills1 = (1 * (int) ($change / 1));
            $change -= $bills1;
            echo ", and $bills1output $1 bills back in cash.</br>";
            $changecents = (int) ($change * 100);
        }
```

Is there a way to do this. I want to convert the change into an integer so its easier to use but that wont work in this while loop because $change is already less the 1.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Would that work? The while loop only runs while Change > 1.

Comment: why don't you add another while AFTER this bill loop, to calculate the coins, multiply $change with 100 to make the comparisons easier

Comment: do you see a pattern in the `if`'s you code, why do you use a `while` and `elseif`

Answer (score 0):

Continue in the same loop looking for the coin denominations in the same way

First change the while loop to run till zero

```
while ($change > 0) {

   . . .

    } elseif ($change >= 0.50) {
        $coinOut50c = (int) ($change / 0.5);
        $coins50c = (0.5 * (int) ($change / 0.5));
        $change -= $coins50c;
        echo ", and $coinOut50c 50cent coins";
    } elseif ($change >= 0.25) {
        $coinOut25c = (int) ($change / 0.25);
        $coins25c = (0.25 * (int) ($change / 0.25));
        $change -= $coins25c;
        echo ", and $coinOut25c quarters";
    }

    . . .

    etc etc until you get to the pennies
```

Admitedly you will only get one of each of these coins but you may get more than one penny

Comment: When I make $change = to $changecents I want to keep $changecents as an Interger so its easier to read and the multiplication isnt as annoying.

Comment: You cant, if you make 0.49 into 49 you will hit the wrong IF ELSE next time round the loop

Comment: This ways its pretty well self documenting as well

Comment: I got it with your help, Thank You

 ````elseif ($change >= 0.25) {
            $coins25out = (int) ($change / 0.25);
            $coins25 = (0.25 * (int) ($change / 0.25));
            $change -= $coins25;
            if ($coins25out > 1) {
                echo "$coins25out | Quarters";
            } else {
                echo "$coins25out | Quarter";
            }````